# Quasi-projective morphism of affine varieties is a polynomial map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have a quasi-projective morphism $F: V \rightarrow W$ for $V, W$ affine varieties (quasi-projective varieties isomorphic to some Zariski closed subset of affine space). I was wondering if $F$ is not only locally polynomial, but 'globally', i.e. the homogeneous polynomials that define the map on open subsets of $V$ is the same for each open subset.

I feel that this may not be the case...however, the polynomial maps defined locally have to agree on the intersections, so there is some restriction to defining any such map.

How do I show that from the definition of a quasi-projective morphism that such a morphism between affine varieties is described as a 'global' polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is impossible: any map of affine varieties $X\to Y$ is equivalent to a map of their coordinate algebras $k[Y]\to k[X]$, which provides you the "global" polynomial description you seek to avoid.

Comment: How do I see this? (Let z.c. variety denote a Zariski closed subset of affine space) I know that a morphism of z.c. varieties gives rise to a homomorphism of coordinate algebras, but why does a quasi-projective morphism behave the same way? The morphism of z.c. varieties is already defined to be "globally" polynomial so this is clear, but the definition of q.p. morphisms seems to be involved in only local behavior so I can't see it in this case.

Comment: Any good definition of affine varieties establishes that the coordinate algebra is an intrinsic invariant of the variety - this means that it does not depend on how we embed the affine variety in any other space. From here, any morphism of affine varieties induces a morphism of coordinate algebras by pullback: if we have $f:X\to Y$, a regular function $g$ on $Y$ pulls back to a regular function $g(f(-))$ on $X$. This morphism of coordinate algebras will then give you the global polynomial description you want.

Comment: Does the following argument make sense: Let $f$ be a q.p. morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y.$ The projection onto the $i^{th}$ coordinate of points in $Y$ is a regular function. Hence, the composition with $f$ is a regular function. That is, the mapping of $f$ onto each coordinate is defined by a rational function, which is in fact a polynomial on $X$. Hence, $f$ is a global polynomial? 

So in fact, we don't really have to differentiate z.c. morphism and q.p. morphism?

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at here. Any morphism of affine varieties gives you a map on coordinate algebras - this is the point of the definition of a morphism of varieties! If you're having specific issues with specific definitions, perhaps you should edit your post to make these clear.

Comment: It seems like I'm supposed to deduce that $f$ is a z.c. morphism from the fact that $g(f(-))$ is a regular function on $X$? Isn't that what I did in my comment? I understand a z.c. morphism of a.a. varieties gives a map on coordinate algebras, but I'm trying to see that a q.p. morphism does the same. To my knowledge, these morphisms aren't defined the same...

Comment: What is this "z.c. morphism" business you're talking about? A morphism of varieties $f:X\to Y$ is _defined_ to take regular functions on $U\subset Y$ to regular functions on $f^{-1}(U)\subset X$ for any $U\subset Y$. It happens that the regular functions on all of $X$ tell you enough to determine the regular functions on any open subset of $X$ if $X$ is affine, and there you go.

Comment: z.c. morphism is a morphism of closed subsets of affine space, i.e. a global polynomial map. The definition you mention is described as a property in my book. In any case, I feel like I use this fact in proving that $f$ is in fact a global polynomial map in the comment above. Is your issue with it that it doesn't work or that it is in fact much more immediate that $f$ is a global polynomial. Sorry for the troubles. I am very new to this and I appreciate your patience.

Comment: First, I don't think there's actually much of an issue here: different books take different definitions, and any good definition of a morphism of varieties will be equivalent to the statement about regular functions on an open subset pulling back to regular functions on that subset's preimage. This, plus the way that regular functions on all of an affine variety tell you about regular functions on any open, is enough to conclude the result. If you have specific questions about the definitional issues, you should edit the specifics in to this question or ask a new question.

Comment: I don't have issues with the definition. I just have trouble going from the definition to seeing that a morphism (quasi projective) of affine varieties is polynomial. Here are my questions.
1. How does a regular function on an affine variety tell us about regular function on any open? Is it simply the restriction?
2. How does 1. plus the definition lead us to conclude the global behavior of the regular function on an affine variety?

Comment: This is getting too long for the comments. Please edit your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103317/discussion-between--and-kreiser).